# How to display elasticsearch query results within a spark dataframe

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark

My elasticsearch query written with python specifies that I want to save only the selected field within a spark dataframe However what I get in the dataframe is all the fields.

```
q ="""{
    "_source": "predicted_cluster",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "mobile_client.keyword": "Diverse PC&Laptop" } },
        { "match": { "browser.keyword": "Internet Explorer 11.x" } },
        { "match": { "city.keyword": "Munich" } },
        { "match": { "new_visitor.keyword": "0" } },
        { "match": { "resolution.keyword": "1920x1080" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}"""

es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf=es_read_conf)
results_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(es_rdd)
```

I expect the spark Dataframe rows to have only predicted_cluster values but what I get is all the fields. How can I write only the selected field within a spark dataframe ?
This is what I get as output
[image]

Comment: I can't really help you, but there is also a spark package avaiable ([link](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/elasticsearch.html)) which has a config parameter [es.query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html).

Comment: I have already installed that package on databricks and followed the instructions on the link but the reading part is not optimised. it takes so long to execute the query which i think this is the opposite of elastic search intention (get fast responses for queries).

Answer (score 0):

Your output is good.
You've transformed your JSON into a spark MapType.
Now all you need to do is use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) to separate the different key, value pairs into different columns.

Unfortunately I canno see the keys of the map inside your rdd, so I'm unable to post accurate code to help.

Comment: Thank you @scr for your reply. It's a way to do it but is there another way to write the query so we have automatically one field as output  exactly like the output of query in curl that we type in the dev console.